# Uncaught Reference Error when calling function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Uncaught ReferenceError: SaveProgrammeData is not defined

Can't get it to call the SaveProgrammeData function inside the script tag when clicking the button. I don't see an issue with scope and so not sure why this is happening

```
<sims-partial name="_FormScripts"></sims-partial>

<script>
function SaveProgrammeData() {

    var subjectArea = $("").val();

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ProgrammeMarketing/SaveProgrammeData",
    data: JSON.stringify({                   
        SubjectArea: subjectArea, 
    }),
    contextType: "application/json",

    Success: function (result) {
        $("#overview").append("<tr><td>") +
        result.SubjectArea + "</td> <td>";     
        }
    })
 }
</script>


<div>
    <select asp-for="SubjectAreas" 
        asp-items="Model.SubjectAreas">
    </select>
    <p><a class="btn btn-default" onclick='SaveProgrammeData()'>Save</a> 
    </p>
</div>


<div>
    <table id="overview" class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>SubjectAreas</th>
        </tr>       
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: The above code won't be generating the error, have you looked at the callstack to see where it's coming from.  Have you any other code that's removing the script etc.  Can you produce a minimal verifiable snippet showing this?.

Comment: Try giving your button an id and set the click event handler with jQuery. `$('#buttonId').on('click', function(){SaveProgrammeData();});`

Comment: Cannot replicate the issue. If I copy paste the code, I get issues with `subjectArea` not referencing the correct element, but the function tries to execute onclick. So I cannot get the `Uncaught ReferenceError: SaveProgrammeData is not defined` error with the code shown.

Answer (score 0):

Call the function inside ready state

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function SaveProgrammeData() {

    var subjectArea = $("").val();

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ProgrammeMarketing/SaveProgrammeData",
    data: JSON.stringify({                   
        SubjectArea: subjectArea, 
    }),
    contextType: "application/json",

    Success: function (result) {
        $("#overview").append("<tr><td>") +
        result.SubjectArea + "</td> <td>";     
        }
    })
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem was a syntax error in the function not picked up by the compiler. I think this was causing the function not to be recognized as a function
Correct code below
Thanks for the suggestions

```
Success: function (result) {
            $("#overview").append("<tr><td>" +
                result.SubjectArea + "</td> <td>" +
                result.OverviewDescription + "</td></tr>");
```